# QGIS 3.34: Permanently saving file name and location for georeferencer's output file

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

Is it at possible to permanently change the file name template for the georeferencer's output raster file?

I would like to save my files as

```
source-directory\georef\original-filename georef.tif
```

instead of

```
source-directory\original-filename_modified.tif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without modifying the source code and compiling yourself:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/a5b4d9743e8cab61df3ad3878a46a44f60be2888/src/app/georeferencer/qgstransformsettingsdialog.cpp#L324

Making this configurable would make a fantastic feature request:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Feature+Request&projects=&template=15_feature_request.yml